# Pandaic way to handle empty strings in isin()

Tags: python, string, pandas

The final print statement below is shows three items when only two 'b' and 'c' are wanted.  What is the pandaic way to not include the empty strings in the result?

```
print(sys.version)
print(np.__version__)
print(pd.__version__)


3.6.4
1.14.2
0.22.0
```

<!- ->

```
import string

ds1 = pd.Series(list(string.ascii_lowercase[:3]), (range(3)))
ds2 = pd.Series(list(string.ascii_lowercase[1:4]), (range(1,4))) 

ds1[0]=''
ds2[3]=''

print(ds1)
0
1    b
2    c
dtype: object

print(ds2)
1    b
2    c
3
dtype: object
```

<!- ->

```
print(ds1[ds1.isin(ds2)]) # returns three items, only want 'b' and 'c'

0
1    b
2    c
dtype: object
```

I tried using isnull() to no avail.

```
print(ds1.isnull())
```

output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty strings do not correspond to NaN, None, etc. Just filter them out like you'd normally do.

```
ds1[ds1.isin(filter(None, ds2))]

1    b
2    c
dtype: object
```

Comment: whoa. what a cool way to take advantage of the falsy-ness of both None and an empty string with a filter. pandasnic ninja-worthy.

Comment: IMO, the proper adjective is "pandorable" - however, here it should be "pythonic" since `filter` is a Python built-in.

Comment: @jpp think I first heard "pandaic" from Andy lol but feel free to petition for a change xD